# Get frames from webcam to picture box

Tags: wpf, winforms, zxing, aforge

As far as I understand,

```
void processor_NewTargetPosition(System.Drawing.Bitmap image)
        {
            IntPtr hBitMap = image.GetHbitmap();
            BitmapSource bmaps = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitMap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            bmaps.Freeze();

            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                pictureBoxMain.Source = bmaps;
            }), DispatcherPriority.Render, null);



        }
```

Those code use to put every frame from webcam to the picture box.
This code works well in WPF. I am trying to convert that to use in window form but no luck because I couldn't find the replacement for these line:

```
BitmapSource bmaps = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitMap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

And

```
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                pictureBoxMain.Source = bmaps;
            }), DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
```

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever looked at the properties of PictureBox?

Comment: Yeah, after add Presentation Core I can create BitmapSource. I also convert bitmapsource once again to bitmap to add to picturebox and use BeginInvoke to replace Dispatcher but it didn't work...

Comment: But you won't want to do that. You could directly put the `image` argument into a PictureBox's `Image` property. No need to do any WPF stuff here.

Comment: Oh yes, how stupid I was... Thanks a lot!!